# Connect through PHP to MySql on EC2 instance with key-based authentication

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running a mysql server, and the server uses key-based authentication to connect to it.  I am needing to connect to the mysql server on this EC2 instance through PHP from a different non-amazon server.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I do this?  Do I need to use ssh2 connection functions in PHP?  Obviously, I can't just use mysql_connect because the server uses key-based authentication.  Any help anyone could give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that by key based authentication you mean ssh keys and not connecting to mysql with keys.

So you have a couple of options.

1. Use an SSH tunnel. This uses an ssh listener on your non-amzn server and forwards all communications to mysql instance via SSH. This is more secure, but not without some overhead.
2. If security is less of a concern you can open your security groups to the ip of the non-amzn server and set up a connection directly to port 3306 (or whatever port you are using)

In any case, you will end up with some latency running queries like this. Depending on the connection between your servers.

Comment: Yes, I mean ssh keys.  How do I establish this connection in php?

Comment: You have to set up the tunnel outside of php. It will run as a separate process. Once you do that, you will be connecting to mysql using localhost as the hostname and the port the tunnel is listening on.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to setup a tunnel. I'm needing to connect to a server through php, but the server uses key-based auth. How do I connect to a server using key-based auth through php?

Comment: The tunnel handles that. All you need to do is connect to the tunnel.

Comment: Oh okay, I see.  I'm gonna try this out.  Thanks for the info.